# Tezos alpha node cors

Tags: tzscan, rpc

I'm send post request to `http://alphanet-node.tzscan.io/blocks/head/context/contracts/<contract_id>/big_map_get`
from google chrome browser. Google chrome browser send option request and node return 404 response.

Comment: Can you post the exact calls you are making?

Comment: http://alphanet-node.tzscan.io/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1Mon9CNLwm7Psdei54ivDkhbx651cZUr4i/big_map_get - this is url and json post params https://pastebin.com/PNUDBKwJ instead of address, wallet address

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending your query to the wrong address - it should be (note you are missing "chain/main/"):

```
https://alphanet-node.tzscan.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/<contract_id>/big_map_get
```

I recommend using the https version too. I have successfully queried this endpoint with a smart contract of my own and verified the response:

```
eztz.node.setProvider("https://alphanet-node.tzscan.io")
eztz.node.query(`/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1WRNhjkXLFZbSKzWDGADNPakX3tVq5a9Ti/big_map_get`, {
  "key": {
      "string": "KT1CUw2XscnBrK8GMu3dmF6poZexXcMet71Y"
   },
   "type": {
       "prim": "address"
   }
}).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```